# Custom db connection in Joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

Is it possible by standard methods create new connection to custom DB in Joomla or i need to use standart php methods in my olugin?

Comment: always possible...but consider also your data type name from your previous Joomla configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yes  you can make new connections.

JDatabaseDriver and its child classes will let you do quite a bit.
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/database/driver.php#L377